# AWK : the ' ' as field separator

Tags: awk

I have those lines from db dump

```
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '33', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '23544', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '343', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '21', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
```

As you seen the second filed is 33, 23544 ,343
using the ' '.

I want to substitute with `awk` with a numeric increasing
filed (1,2,3..), I know how to do using `$2++`,but I don't know
how to pass the `'` as a field separator.

Using this syntax give me error:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "' '" } ; { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
awk -F\' '{print $2}'
```

Just escape the `'`

Getting the output field separator back takes a bit more quoting, but can be done by setting OFS inside `awk`.  Putting it all together with your question it would look like (with much appreciated cleanup from @Peter.O):

```
awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{$2++;print}'
```

Comment: Or: `awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{$2++;print}'`